# I'm getting IndexOutOfBoundsException when i try to deselect multiple checked check boxes

Tags: android

I have a code where i can check multiple check boxes and and show text in textview. When i uncheck particular checkbox text should be remove. But when i try to do it i'm facing IOBException.[image: Below is the image of my code]

getting error at userItemsList.remove(position)

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            mBuilder.setTitle("Available Courses");
            mBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(courseItems, checkedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int position, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked){
                        if (!userItemsList.contains(position)){
                            userItemsList.add(position);
                        }
                    }else if (userItemsList.contains(position)){
                        userItemsList.remove(position);
                    }
                }
            });
            mBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            mBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                    StringBuilder item = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i=0; i < userItemsList.size(); i++){
                        item.append(courseItems[userItemsList.get(i)]);

                        if (i != userItemsList.size()-1){
                            item.append(",");
                        }
                    }
                    textView.setText(item.toString());
                }
            });
            mBuilder.setNegativeButton("Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });

            mBuilder.setNeutralButton("Clear All", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    for (int n = 0; n < checkedItems.length; n++){
                        checkedItems[n] = false;
                        userItemsList.clear();
                        textView.setText("");
                    }
                }
            });
            AlertDialog mDialog = mBuilder.create();
            mDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please post code snippets instead of a screen shot

Comment: The position provided by the DialogInterface callback is not the position of the button you clicked relative to ```userListItem``` but but relative to the ```checkedItems``` list you provided. From this code alone, i'm convinced those are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Hashmap for filling your checklist instead of list and change true to false whenever user deselect the box .

Answer (score 0):

is userItemList an ArrayList of Integer?

ArrayList.contains(Object) -- no problem if you use int as parameter, it will autobox to Integer.

ArrayList.remove(int) -- error! this will use the parameter as index, instead of autobox it to Integer.

Comment: this is the way: userItemList.remove(userItemList.indexOf(position))

Answer (score 0):

You're adding Dialogs position to the list that's why its throwing IOB Exception. you should add item name to List and check if it is present or not..

I have updated your code. *Tested it*. It will work fine now !

```
String[] courseItems = new String[]{"a", "x", "b", "c" };
boolean[] checkedItems = new boolean[]{false, false, false, false };
List<String> userItemsList;


AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Splash.this);
   mBuilder.setTitle("Available Courses");
   mBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(courseItems, checkedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int position, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                  if (!userItemsList.contains(courseItems[position])) {
                      userItemsList.add(courseItems[position]);
                  }
            } else if (userItemsList.contains(courseItems[position])) {
                    userItemsList.remove(courseItems[position]);
                }
           }
            });
            mBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            mBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                    StringBuilder item = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i=0; i < userItemsList.size(); i++){
                        item.append(userItemsList.get(i));

                        if (i != userItemsList.size()-1){
                            item.append(",");
                        }
                    }
                     textView.setText(item.toString());
                }
            });
            mBuilder.setNegativeButton("Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });

            mBuilder.setNeutralButton("Clear All", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    for (int n = 0; n < checkedItems.length; n++){
                        checkedItems[n] = false;
                        userItemsList.clear();
                        textView.setText("");
                    }
                }
            });
            AlertDialog mDialog = mBuilder.create();
            mDialog.show();
```

Happy Coding :)